# ReactiveCrudRepository, MySQL, Entity Mapping

Tags: spring-webflux

I have three tables in MySQL

1. Employee (id, name, salary)
2. Department (id, name) which have static master data,
3. EmployeeDeptRef (id,emp_id,dept_id) which maps both employee and department. One employee may belong to multiple departments.

I am able to store the data in Employee table using ReactiveCrudRepository which in turn has to store the data in EmployeeDeptRef but it is not happening.

Tried with OneToMany mapping but facing exception like MySQL dialect doesn't support array data.

Could someone please provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nested entities are not yet supported in R2DBC.

[You can also read this article](https://tolkiana.com/avoiding-nested-streams-spring-webflux/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply HoustoN. Is there anyway we can achieve above requirement.  With Spring Webflux.